# I have a problem with the result of a postgresql window function

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

i have this postgresql table in the 'inv' schema:

```
CREATE TABLE vouchers (
    id BIGSERIAL,
    proveedor VARCHAR,
    numero_serie VARCHAR,
    numero_correlativo INT,
    oficina VARCHAR,
    fecha_operacion DATE,
    numero_operacion INT,
    hora_operacion TIME with time zone,
    importe DEC(9,2),
    adquiriente VARCHAR,
    cliente VARCHAR
);
```

and this rows:

[My csv file with data](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkW7YUl_4KH743sLYo8Tnn_DKIwQ?e=5omlix)
This data is rdy to import without headers, column order is:

```
proveedor,
numero_serie,
numero_correlativo,
oficina,
fecha_operacion,
numero_operacion,
hora_operacion,
importe;
```

The problem is, when i execute

```
SELECT id,proveedor,LAG (id,1) OVER (PARTITION BY fecha_operacion ORDER BY fecha_operacion) as result FROM inv.vouchers
```

the query results with null rows like this

[image: results]

I'm quite confused, I don't know what could be happening

The expected result is:

```
| id | proveedor | id |
|----|-----------|----|
|   1|kenthiva   |null|
|   2|tisocni    |   1|
|   3|kenthiva   |   2|
|   4|cherrys    |   3|
|   5|cherrys    |   4|
|   6|cherrys    |   5|
|   7|tisocni    |   6|
|   8|cherrys    |   7|
|   9|kenthiva   |   8|
|  10|kenthiva   |   9|
.
.
.
| 358|cach       | 357|
| 359|consulceliz| 358|
| 360|kenthiva   | 359|
| 361|cach       | 360|
```

Comment: When there is no lag() you get a null. You could use coalesce () to replace is with a zero, if you like

Comment: @FrankHeikens I understand that, but every row has a vale, in this case table doesnt have null values. Look my query, I select id column and this is a bigserial type doesnt have nulls

Comment: Use LAG (id, 1, 0) where 0 is your default value when is no rows before the current row

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect, as tabular text (no images). `LAG` needs an `ORDER BY` clause to make sense.

Comment: @GMB i updated my question, my precise question is why it returns null when there is a value to return.The id column always has a value so there will always be an id in the previous row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was here `SELECT id,proveedor,LAG (id,1) OVER (PARTITION BY fecha_operacion ORDER BY fecha_operacion) as result FROM inv.vouchers`, in the 'PARTITION BY' clause, this partition by fecha_operacion. I removed that and solve this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).